# Using the Session class during Laravel 4 app configuration

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4

Is it possible to access the `Session` class in my *app/config/app.php* file?

I am able to use `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;` but not `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;` (or `Cookie` for that matter) at this stage of the app request.

I think it may be a good way to store my debug toggle for my development environment. I will toggle debug via a **GET** variable and would like it to last throughout a session (or until I unset it), rather than until the next request which will not include the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contig files are loaded very early in the app's lifetime, I'm surprised even `Input` works. No, there is no way to use session variables in the config files themselves. You could use an app event to change the config values at runtime, `App::booting` should be appropriate for this. In app/start/global.php:

```
App::booting(function() {
    if (Session::get(...)) Config::set(...);
});
```

Note that this may not always have the results you expect. For example, as soon as the app is started, it checks the config for app.debug == true and chooses its exception handler accordingly, so if you'd want to change the exception handler after the app has started, you'd have to do it directly via `app('exception')->setDebug(true)`. There may be any number of similar configurations you need to do, depending on your setup.

Comment: Excellent, thanks Andreas. I understand the restrictions and appreciate your option for the earliest solution in the request